# System of equations with two unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If I have three equations with two unknowns $(X, Y)$ , what should I do?

I check that one is linearly dependent? 
and then I delete it.

Thank you.

Comment: What system of equations?

Answer (score 3):

I would solve it based on two of the equations, and then substitute your answer for the third. If it matches, then it does not affect the answer. However, it it does not work (e.g., end up with $-1=0$ or similar), then there is no solution.

Comment: yes, but if I have the following system with three unknowns (X, Y) and two indeterminate values. How could study its compatibility? 

a*X + a*Y = 2; 
(a-1)*X + 2*a*Y = 3-a; 
(a + 1)*X = a + 1;

Comment: I would solve for a in these cases, and if the resulting expression is equal to the others, then they are the same equation.

Comment: @Jose Notice that if $(a+1)X=a+1$, then $a=-1$ or $x=1$.